# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I have absolutely no idea why I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../minimal.py", line 8, in <module>
    obj = Clazz([0], [[0], [0]], [[0]])
  File ".../minimal.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.c = c
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'c'
```

from the following piece of code

```
class Clazz(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self,b = b
        self.c = c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Clazz([0], [[0], [0]], [0])
```

When I only pass

```
obj = Clazz([0], [0], [0])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../minimal.py", line 8, in <module>
    obj = Clazz([0], [[0], [0]], [0])
  File ".../minimal.py", line 4, in __init__
    self,b = b
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I tried to google it but there where no similar problems. How can that happen? What is the reason for these errors?

Comment: `self,b = b` should be `self.b = b`, but this may be an error in the question format as in your error it says `self.b`

Comment: `self,b` should be `self.b`

Comment: The difference between code and error happens when you do not just copy paste. :D

Comment: That's actually nice: when you write `self,b = b` with `b = [[0], [0]]`, then `self` takes `[0]` and thus become a list. Then you can't do `self.c = [0]` the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a dot `.` here:

```
self.b = b
```

When you pass this:

```
obj = Clazz([0], [[1], [2]], [0])  #   self, b = [[1], [2]]
```

your code assigns `[1]` to self, and `[2]` to b, so running `self.c` is going to raise:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'c'
```

For the second case: `obj = Clazz([0], [1], [0])`

`self, b` requires `[1]` to have two items. So, it raises:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: OK... Thanks! I did not see this. The formatting of my editor was really bad. :D

Comment: Of course, I just had to wait for some minutes. :)